# I get an error code 401 when create a call use graph explorer

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I try to create a call using graph explorer, but i get an error code 401 and 
a message as "Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions. "

I already  set permissions through Azure active directory.

```
Calls.Initiate.All
Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All
Calls.JoinGroupCall.All
Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All
```

request as follows:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/calls
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "callbackUri": "https://bot.contoso.com/api/calls",
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.appHostedMediaConfig",
    "blob": "<media config blob>"
  },
  "requestedModalities": [ "audio" ],
  "source": {
    "identity": {
      "application": {
        "id": "MyRealApplicationCode",
        "tenantId": MyRealTenantId,
        "displayName": "IT Bot"
      }
    },
    "languageId": "languageId-value",
    "region": "region-value"
  },
  "subject": "Test Call",
  "targets": [
    {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "MyRealUserId",
          "tenantId": MyRealTenantId,
          "displayName": "Heidi Steen"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "tenantId": "tenantId-value"
}
```

response as follows:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"9000\",\"message\":\"Unsupported AAD Identity.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b0232477-048b-486b-9d43-77aacfb3fa2f",
            "date": "2019-07-16T06:44:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use graph explorer to test this api since this api does't support delegated permission which used by graph explorer. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions) is the difference between delegated permission and application permission.

[image]

You need to get an access token by using [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), then use this access token to call this api. Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) for the detailed steps.